# mysqldump executes but backup file is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to backup a MySQL database with this code:

```
$user="admin";
$pass="";
$dbname="mobiledb";
$backupFile = 'c:\\onstor.sql';
$command = "mysqldump  -u ".$user." -p".$pass." ".$dbname." > ".$backupFile;
system($command);
```

The `onstor.sql` file gets created but its size is 0 bytes!

What's the problem with this?

Comment: run the command from the command line, does it work? any errors?

Comment: it has the same error.the empty file is created

Comment: quite a few matches for 'mysqldump empty' if you use the site search, hopefully one of those will help

Answer (score 3):

Try referencing mysqldump absolutely: /usr/bin/mysqldump

Or in Windows it might be something like this: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the correct privileges to run mysqldump against your database.

As root run:

```
    GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON *.* TO admin@localhost
```

If still no luck, to help with identifying the root cause of the problem, run your mysqldump command from the command line (not via a script) just incase it is due to some file permission issues during standard output redirection.